# How to convert blob to image and display it on React?

Tags: reactjs, image, blob

i have some png images stored as blob in a database and i am trying to get these blob data and convert them to url.

```
<Popup trigger={openPopup} setTrigger={setPopup}>
    <img src={setBlobImages(photoBlob)} />
</Popup>
```

```
function setBlobImages(photo){
    if(photo === undefined){
        console.log("undefined");
        return undefined
    }
    else{
        console.log("value")
        var binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(photo);
        return URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData))
    }
}
```

The result:
[image]

How can i make this work? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `<img src={photoBlob} />`?

Comment: doesn't work :/

Comment: can you paste your blob?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Adding "data:image/png;base64," solved the problem.

Example:

```
<img className="blob-to-image" src={"data:image/png;base64," + photoBlob}></img>
```